# How to search in mysql table where field in json array field?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, join, select

I have a table with JSON array field,
I want a query that returns results from another table based on this field

table_a

```
+----+-------------+
| id | interestIds |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | [1, 2, 6, 7]|
+----+-------------+
```

table_b

```
+----+-------------+
| id | country     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Ghana       |
|  2 | Grenada     |
|  3 | Jordan      |
|  4 | Latvia      |
|  5 | Malawi      |
|  6 | Mexico      |
|  7 | Moldova     |
+----+-------------+
```

i want query like

```
select * from table_b where id in (select interestIds from table_a where id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_search()`:

```
select b.*
from table_b
where exists (
    select 1 from table_a a where json_search(a.interestIds, 'one', b.id) is not null
)
```